# How can I generate keywords associated with a website given its URL?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, supervised-learning, text-summarization

I have a column with links to websites and another column with keywords from those websites. I have to find a map between these two, such that for a new input, which is a website's URL, I can generate the keywords associated with the contents of the website.

For example, given the URL `chocolate.com`, the keywords could be `milk` and `dark`. We can tell from this example that my keywords are types of chocolates.

Or, if the URL is `career.com`, then the keywords could be `IT` and `medicine`.

I have a feeling that some sort of supervised neural networks could be used here.   Which approach would be most suited here?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. First, you're talking about links but you probably mean the contents of web pages. Second, it is unclear whether you want to associate keywords from a given list with web page contents, or whether you plan to identify keywords from the text even if they weren't part of training data. The first task would be fairly simple, but I have no idea how the second task could be done. If you try to word your requirements precisely, you might get a knowledgeable answer...

Comment: I have edited the original post. To reply to your questions, yes, I mean the content of web pages and yes I have to associate a link between the content of those webpages and the keywords.